# RuntimeError: stack expects a non-empty TensorList Tortoise TTS

Tags: python, google-notebook

I'm trying to run this tortoise tts python google notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1g_CssJK34kwRi7VRtFd73WvTLq9UbnZT?usp=sharing#scrollTo=CSjn1jNfgA1y and am getting this error. The error is happening when gen is declared.

```
all_parts = []
for j, text in enumerate(texts):
    gen = tts.tts_with_preset(text, voice_samples=voice_samples, conditioning_latents=conditioning_latents,
                              preset="fast", k=1, use_deterministic_seed=seed)
    gen = gen.squeeze(0).cpu()
    torchaudio.save(os.path.join(voice_outpath, f'{j}.wav'), gen, 24000)
    all_parts.append(gen)

full_audio = torch.cat(all_parts, dim=-1)
torchaudio.save(os.path.join(voice_outpath, 'combined.wav'), full_audio, 24000)
IPython.display.Audio(os.path.join(voice_outpath, 'combined.wav'))
```